# View controller dismissal animation parameters

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller

I am showing a `UIViewController` in a separate `UIWindow`. This view controller presents another `UIViewController`. When presented view controller is dismissed, I need to dismiss the `UIWindow` as well (without user seeing it), so I need to know what animation, duration and curve are used by iOS when dismissing a view controller.

How can I find this out? I can guess, but it would be nice to know exactly. Ideally, I would like to have some way of referencing default system animations.

---

**EDIT:** The way to go would probably be just to animate the dismissal of window, and then dismiss presented view controller without animation. But anyway it would be nice to know the exact animation parameters to make it look exactly the same as view controller dismissal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the completionBlock of the `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion`:

```
// dismiss the view controller
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    // dismiss the window when presented view controller is dismissed
}];
```

---

**EDIT:** Why not you dismiss the window when the another UIViewController is presented? You can presents the another view controller to the rootViewController of the keyWindow

Comment: I was probably not clear enough. With this approach, I will see the window and presenting view controller, which I do not want.

Comment: Regarding your edit, yes, I can just dismiss the window with animation, but it would be nice to know the parameters to make it look like view controller is being dismissed.